# Laravel 8 does not know route other than "/" on the server

Tags: laravel, amazon-ec2

I am experiencing a problem when uploading laravel 8 to the service, it is only recognizing the "/" route and nothing else, then I am receiving the following error "The requested URL was not found on this server."
However if I indicate "domain/index.p/route", then it works normally, I saw several articles indicating that it was on apache2 in the .conf file but I couldn't configure it in case I'm using debian on EC2.
How could I be solving this issue?

**.conf file**

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster
        DocumentRoot /var/www/directory/public

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/directory>
                 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                 AllowOverride All
                 Require all granted
        </Directory>




        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: did you enable url rewrite module?

Comment: Yes I enabled rewrite module

Comment: 99% of problems like this are solved by one of:
1. ensure modrewrite is enabled. sudo a2enmod rewrite 
2. ensure AllowOverride is set to All in the site config, as you have done above
3. ensure AllowOVerride is set to All in the core apache config file as well
4. restart apache. apache2ctl restart

Comment: Thanks friend it was just so in the apache2 configuration file